# How can I hide part of post title when the webpage shrinks?

Tags: html, css

i have a list of posts.

i want print some words of post content with post title

just like GMAIL ( old design )

```
$TopicTitle='social networks';
$SmallDescription='The ability to easily bookmark or share content on popular social media platforms';
echo '<p class="title">'.$TopicTitle.'</p>'.' - <span class="desc">'.$SmallDescription.'</span>';
//this will prints
//social networks - The ability to easily bookmark or share content on popular social media platforms
```

And it works fine..

But...

if user has small monitor or had resized page to small

The page will be not enough for the big title, so it will have a new like

like this

```
//social networks - The ability to easily bookmark or share content 
//on popular social media platforms
```

will have a new line!

So, i want make something profissional like Gmail

while you are shrinking the page, the title is shrinking too, i don't mean the size of title, i mean the title itself, will became like this

```
//social networks - The ability to easily bookmark or share content
```

Some of title has been deleted, i don't know how they do this, java or html!

i want do this trick to save the butey of my design

if you did not understood me

please see this picture

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the exact way Google did this, but there are many possible solutions. Here's one that comes to mind:

First, limit the height of your titles to the same of your `line-height` and specify `overflow: hidden;` for them. Then optionally replace the spaces you don't want to cut off at with `&nbsp;`. This way when the container is resized, the title is wrapped to another line which is not displayed.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2jwT/) for a demonstration.

Comment: FAntastic! it's exactly what i want, Thank you very much

Comment: **+1** Also, consider the CSS `white-space` rule too. Here's an update [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c2jwT/1/).

Comment: i have already checked it, but i think first example is better

Comment: @AlaaGamal, to be sure, the update jsFiddle is original jsFiddle with additional CSS rule named `white-space` that may save you time. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [**jQuery ThreeDots Plugin**](http://tpgblog.com/2009/12/21/threedots-the-jquery-ellipsis-plugin/).

This place **Ellipsis** at end of text line when it's too long.

Ellipsis = `...`

**Example:** `This virtual long text-line is really long with many charact...`

Here's the plugin's [**Demo Page**](http://theproductguy.com/threedots/threedots.demo.html) with many live examples!

Comment: +1 this is good solution too, but unfortunally i don't use jquery

Comment: Glad you found an Answer that worked for your specific requirements.